# Returning a value in a function of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following snippet returns `undefined` instead of an expected array of links. apiCall() is from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Is it possible to return the array? If so how? If not why?

```
async function fetchData() {

   await apiCall('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=leeroyjenkins&maxResults=4&part=snippet&key={KEY}', 
       (error, response, body) => {
      return JSON.parse(body).items.map(i => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + i.id.videoId)

            })

}
  fetchData().then(r => console.log(r))
```

EDIT: The following code seems to work;

```
async function fetchData(param, fn) {

   await apiCall('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=leeroyjenkins&maxResults=4&part=snippet&key={KEY}', 
       (error, response, body) => {
      fn(JSON.parse(body).items.map(i => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + i.id.videoId))

            })

}
fetchData('lee', function(Ar) { console.log(Ar) })

};
```

Can someone point out why?

Comment: _If not why?_ - `apiCall` doesn't return a Promise, doesn't it?

Comment: this function return is not aync, it does not return a promise,

Comment: closer analysis shows that a maped values return, which is not a promise interface.

Comment: Well, if I console.log `fetchData()` , it outputs Promise{ <pending> } @Remario @Federkun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await`is used to *wait* for a *Promise*. `apiCall` isn't one, it uses the continuation-passing style convention. So, you just need to resolve a new promise when the `apiCall`'s callback is called:

```
async function fetchData() {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
        apiCall('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=leeroyjenkins&maxResults=4&part=snippet&key={KEY}', (error, response, body) => {
            // resolve the promise here
            resolve(JSON.parse(body).items.map(i => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + i.id.videoId))
        })
    }); 
}
```

Comment: using async and await should eliminate the need for explicit promises, good solution but it defies the concept of aync/wait

Comment: What do you mean? async/await are built on top of generators and promises: you can't use them without promises. Since `apiCall` isn't returns a promise, you have to "promisify" it.

Comment: question, if your explicitly using promises, why await it with a async, when you reolve it, whats the catch, thats redundant right. removing the async and await keywords, should yield no difference.

Comment: Yeah, in this specific example `async`/`await` don't serve any purpose. Yet, the question was "why my code returns undefined", and hopefully now the OP knows why. If you want improve your answer with a "your fetchData could just returns a promise" you are welcome to do it. I think that would help Nothingness understand better what he _really_ want to accomplish with his `fetchData`.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
async function fetchData() {

   await apiCall('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=leeroyjenkins&maxResults=4&part=snippet&key={KEY}', 
       (error, response, body) => {
      return JSON.parse(body).items.map(i => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + i.id.videoId)

            })

}
```

to:

```
async function fetchData() {

   return await apiCall('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=leeroyjenkins&maxResults=4&part=snippet&key={KEY}'); 

}
```

try promise execution here:

```
 fetchData().then(r => console.log(r))
```

Comment: then on r do, JSON.parse(r).items.map(i => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + i.id.videoId)